# How to create a header for a website that i can change in one file using node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a node.js header for a website I'm working on from a video, but no matter how much the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VShtPwEkDD0) claimed to be simple, I cannot fiqure out what I'm doing wrong

```js
const http = require('http'); 
const fs = require("fs");
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
    fs.readFile('Header.html', function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Error: Header not found')
        } else {
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end()
    })
}) 

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong: " + error);
    } else {
        console.log("Server is up and running on port " + port);
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to happen and what is actually happening? Do you get any errors? One of possible issues with your code is that the `readFile` function returns a buffer so you are sending a buffer to the browser which is probably not what you want. You should send a string. To fix that try `res.write(data.toString())` or pass a encoding to `readFile` and it will return a string.

Comment: @Molda I expect to write to the screen withwhatever is in my html file and I get an error which the error inside the if statement(Error: Header not found)

Comment: Could you make sure you have read access to the file? `ls -lla Header.html` ?

Comment: So I that I was being fancy by adding a source folder, but apperently if you put the html file and the javascript file in the source folder, you cannot do fs.readFile("hHeader.html), you would have to do fs.readFile(".src/Header.html) or move the html back into the main folder